MDNavigationDrawerItem AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_active_color'
When clicking on my MDNavigationDrawerItem "Receptenboek", I get the following error when on_release is called:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_active_color'

So far I've tried removing all unnecessary parts of my code, to no avail, the print('switch_to_receptenboek called') does print, though after that it goes wrong somewhere. I haven't been able to find a single similar error to mine
This is my code:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

KV = '''
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        name: "home"
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDTopAppBar:
                title: "Home"
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
            
            MDNavigationLayout:
                MDNavigationDrawer:
                    id: nav_drawer

                    MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                        text: "Receptenboek"
                        on_release: app.switch_to_receptenboek()

    Screen:
        name: "receptenboek"
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            
            MDTopAppBar:
                title: "Receptenboek"
                left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: app.switch_to_home()]]

            MDLabel:
                text: "This is the Receptenboek screen"
                halign: "center"
'''

class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
    def switch_to_receptenboek(self):
        self.root.current = "receptenboek"
        print('switch_to_receptenboek called')

    def switch_to_home(self):
        self.root.current = "home"

TestNavigationDrawer().run()

EDIT: Ended up moving away from MDNavigationDrawerItem, couldn't fix the issue.
